# Can not uninstall an app(hi app lock) which has device administrator rights

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, uninstallation

I have installed "hi app lock" application 2 year ago. But rarely used it. Now when i open it, it doesn't open. So i decided to uninstall it, but first i have to revoke its administration rights. So i try to unchecked it, but that action is crashing. Attached image of uninstall steps. Please let me know how to remove this app. I don't want to factory reset or root my android device(oneplus one, OS: Cynogen OS version: 13.2.1....)[image: device administrator rights screen]

[image: when uncheck admin, app crashed]

Comment: Boot into safe mode and than try disabling the administrator.

Comment: @firelord, same problem when unchecked device administration rights in safe mode.

Comment: Fixed the probem.

Comment: After viewing report's call stack, got to know that android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

for this app is not enabled. So, i enabled above setting by help of this link, https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28947878/How-to-enable-android-permission-SYSTEM-ALERT-WINDOW-in-marshmallow.html and then successfully revoke device administrator right and uninstalled it.

Comment: @ChetanRaiyani Please post that as an answer and mark your question as solved.. Also, edit the question title and include the app name so that it'll be easy to find for others searching via Search Engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing report's call stack, got to know that android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

for this app is not enabled. So, i enabled above setting by help of this link, https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28947878/How-to-enable-android-permission-SYSTEM-ALERT-WINDOW-in-marshmallow.html and then successfully revoke device administrator right and uninstalled it.